# Why can't I change the level of python logger?

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to change the loglevel of a python logger. But it does not seem to work:

```
import logging

#50 CRITICAL
#40 ERROR
#30 WARNING <-- default
#20 INFO
#10 DEBUG
# 0 NOTSET 

logger = logging.getLogger('a')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
print('log level', logger.getEffectiveLevel())
logger.debug('Debug') # 10
logger.info('Info') # 20
logger.warning('Warning') # 30
logger.error('Error') # 40
```

The output is:

```
log level 10
Warning
Error
```

But should be:

```
log level 10
Debug
Info
Warning
Error
```

Why is that and what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the default logging handler handles only the default logging levels.
You have to add a logging handler that does the actual logging.
If you need just console logging, you could use:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('a')
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
...
```

This gets you:

```
log level 10
Debug
Info
Warning
Error
```

`logging.basicConfig()` adds a handler with some basic formatting, but usually you will define your own format for logging.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to set the basic config before logging the messages. Like this:

```
logging.basicConfig()
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you've set the level of the logger, the message has to pass through a handler which has a log level also. The rule is that the most restrictive log level wins. There are several solutions. Broadly you can use `basicConfig` to setup the logging root and it will be inherited by child loggers like "a". Or set a handler for "a".

```
import logging

#50 CRITICAL
#40 ERROR
#30 WARNING <-- default
#20 INFO
#10 DEBUG
# 0 NOTSET 

# option - set a basic config for root logger and its descendents
#logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger('a')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# option = create a handler for this logger
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(handler)

print('log level', logger.getEffectiveLevel())
logger.debug('Debug') # 10
logger.info('Info') # 20
logger.warning('Warning') # 30
logger.error('Error') # 40
```